# Webpack/Typescript for a library file, How to treeshake imports, but not treeshake exports?

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

I'm  a bit new to this all, so i might be using webpack wrong.

Our requirements:
I have a file, that contains objects which need to be referenced in typescript/javascript files. That file is massive, which is why I'd like to treeshake it down to only the specific properties used. That file looks about like this:

```
    export const Fieldnames = {
        testObject: {
            "testfield1":"testfield1",
            "testfield2":"testfield2",
            "testfield3":"testfield3",
            "testfield4":"testfield4",
            "testfield5":"testfield5",
            "testfield6":"testfield6",
        },
    }
```

I then want to create several library files, which expose (export?) javascript functions, so that I can upload these files to a website, and the website can idependently call these functions. This is a bit important: VisualStudioCode/Webpack have no understanding of the fact that I need these functions in tact, and exposed, and just treeshakes away those not immediately called. My TS file looks like this:

Here's the TS source file:

```
    import {Fieldnames} from "../Earlybound/FieldnamesTest";

    export function testFunctionNeverCalled() {
      console.log(`never called survived. ${Fieldnames.testObject.testfield1}`);
    }

    export function testFunctionCalled () {
      console.log(`Called survived. ${Fieldnames.testObject.testfield3}`);
    }

    testFunctionCalled();
```

And here's the result:

```
( () => {
"use strict";
console.log("Called survived. testfield3")
})();
```

The problem here is that "testFunctionNeverCalled" has disappeared. The testobject and the testfields have been integrated exactly how I wanted them to.

My webpack.config.js looks like this:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        inputfile1: './src/inputfile1.ts',
    },
    mode: "production",
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                use: 'ts-loader',
                include: [path.resolve(__dirname,'src')]
            },
        ]
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname,"../JavascriptOutput/")
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx'],
    },
    optimization: {
    mangleExports: true,
    usedExports:true,
    }

}
```

Am i not supposed to use webpack here? Is there an alternative? I'm grateful for any input. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One possibility I've finally discovered is outputting everything into a library like this:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        wscrm_vehicle: './src/wscrm_vehicle.ts',
        wscrm_vehicle2: './src/wscrm_vehicle2.ts',
        lead: './src/lead.ts'
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname,"../JavascriptOutput/"),
        filename: '[name].js',
        libraryTarget: 'var',
        library: 'functions'
    },
```

This gave me the feollowing output, which is

```
var functions;
(() => {
    "use strict";
    var e = {
            d: (t, o) => {
                for (var n in o) e.o(o, n) && !e.o(t, n) && Object.defineProperty(t, n, {
                    enumerable: !0,
                    get: o[n]
                })
            },
            o: (e, t) => Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(e, t),
            r: e => {
                "undefined" != typeof Symbol && Symbol.toStringTag && Object.defineProperty(e, Symbol.toStringTag, {
                    value: "Module"
                }), Object.defineProperty(e, "__esModule", {
                    value: !0
                })
            }
        },
        t = {};
    e.r(t), e.d(t, {
        testFunctionCalled: () => r,
        testFunctionNeverCalled: () => l
    });
    const o = "testfield1",
        n = "testfield3";

    function l() {
        console.log("never called survived. " + o)
    }

    function r() {
        console.log("Called survived. " + n)
    }
    r(), functions = t
})();
```

Which works surprisingly well!